# Plotting in R ggplot- beginner

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a project at work where I am trying to plot data on movies.

My goal is to plot 'definite interest' & 'total awareness' both on the Y-axis and 'estimated admissions' on the X-axis. I will be using ggplot2 and will have both Y- values in different colors.

The main issue I am having is filtering the movies by 'year' and 'window' in ggplot. The window I want is T-0 and the year of release should be 2018. Since I only know how to implement values on the X- and Y-Axis in ggplot without conditions, I could use some guidance.

How should I go about filtering the data and plotting the X and Y's? The excel sheet is attached. Also, I understand the code may not be correct, but I come from a Java background, so no idea what I am doing.

[Excel input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPPJk.png)

```
If my_data$window = T-0 {
  my_data$window <- TRUE 
} else { 
FALSE 
}
```

I expected to make 'window' true if T-0 = TRUE. I attempted the same for 'year'

```
x <- my_data$estimatedAdmissions
y1 <- my_data$definiteInterest 
y2 <- my_data$totalAwareness
plot(x, y1, y2, filter 1, filter 2)
```

I expect to plot those values and will change y1 & y2 to different colors later.

Comment: You can use the package `dplyr` for easy filtering: `my_data <- my_data %>% filter(window == "T-0" & year == 2018)`. However, plotting two different y axes with `ggplot2` is a bit tricky as the package is opinionated about not doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a reproducible example next time - we can't copy your screenshot into R, so I had to recreate your dataset myself like so.

```r
dat <- data.frame(year = 2018,
                  title = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 6),
                  estimatedAdmissions = rep(c(287351, 29518), each = 6),
                  window = rep(c("T+2", "T+1", "T-0", "T-1", "T-2", "T-3"), 2),
                  definiteInterest = c(13, 15, 25, 22, 16, 27, 15, 14, 23, 20, 28, 29),
                  totalAwareness = round(runif(4, 31, n = 12)))
```

You can use `subset` to filter rows, and then `ggplot` with `geom_point` to create a scatterplot. Ggplot works best with data in long format, so I reshaped your data longer with `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr` first.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat |> subset(year == 2018 & window == "T-0") |>
        pivot_longer(cols = c(definiteInterest, totalAwareness), names_to = "measure", values_to = "percentage") |> 
        ggplot(aes(x = estimatedAdmissions, y = percentage, colour = measure)) +
        geom_point()
```

Comment: I apologize for not including the Excel output directly, but this is extremely well-explained! Thank you